# Python Selenium Datepicker select date

Tags: python, selenium, datepicker

I am trying select date with date no.
url:http://www.szse.cn/disclosure/bond/notice/index.html
I am trying: for the start month & date,

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='monthselect'][1]//li[text()='{}']".format("1")))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//table[@class='table-condensed'])[1]//tbody/div[@class='tdcontainer' and contains(text()='15')]"))).click()
```

I can go with like tr[2]//td[3] but I want just use the date no. like 1,2,3..

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I did it by typing the date, not by using the datepicker. In my experience, this is the more reliable way.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def run():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Windows\chromedriver.exe")

    driver.get('http://www.szse.cn/disclosure/bond/notice/index.html')

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10, poll_frequency=1)
    element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "input-left")))

    s1 = driver.find_element_by_class_name('input-left')
    s1.send_keys("2021-03-03")

    s2 = driver.find_element_by_class_name('input-right')
    s2.send_keys("2021-03-04")

    s3 = driver.find_element_by_id("query-btn")
    s3.click()

    time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! you just give me another way to deal with datepicker, many thanks! but may I ask if any datepicker can be sent keys or just some with input?

Comment: You're welcome! I've dealt with some Kendo UI for jQuery datepickers and sending keys to their input worked too.

Comment: That's been my experience too. Different date pickers work in different ways, so you need to treat them individually to figure out how to interact with them.